# Is it possible to prevent :root styles from bleeding into a shadowed component?

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I've created a web component using Stencil that uses the shadow DOM and needs to ignore any CSS that has been added to the page (it has its own stylesheet). To that end, I've included the usual fix to the component stylesheet:

```css
:host {
  all: initial;
}
```

This works to reset any base styles set on the page using the `<style>` tag or an external stylesheet. However, if an inherited style like `font-size` is defined on the `:root` or `html` elements, its value is used when computing a relative value (e.g. `1rem`) instead of using the browser's base size or a font size specified in my component's CSS.

In this example, my dev tools are showing that a `font-size: 160px` value applied to the `:root` is being used to calculate the final font size for an element that has been given `font-size: 0.875rem`, even though I've used the CSS reset above and tried to apply my own base of `16px`.

[image: Dev tools displaying final result of 140px when using a font-size of 0.875rem]

I've done a fair bit of research regarding styles applied to the `:root` element, but have not found an answer. Is there a way to override styles used to compute relative values if they are set on the `:root`?

Comment: ``font-size`` is an [inheritable style](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/)

Comment: Yep. I mentioned that in my issue. The question is why the value from `:root` is bleeding through the override on `:host` and even taking precedence over a value set there.

Comment: **rem** is based on ``:root``, not on ``:host`` Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: I guess you're saying the answer to my question is "no". Do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playground: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/L5kbf8qm/

```html
<style>
  :root {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
</style>
<my-element all="initial"></my-element>
<my-element all="inherit">Note we get the UA 8px margin back</my-element>
<script>
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        let all = this.getAttribute("all");
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
          .innerHTML = `<style>`+
                       `  :host{all:${all}}` +
                       `  div{font-size:2rem;background:pink}`+
                       `</style>` +
                       `<div>Component all:${all}</div>`+
                       `<span id=result ></span><slot></slot>`;
      const add = (name) => {
        let size = window.getComputedStyle(this.shadowRoot.querySelector(name))["font-size"];
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#result").append(`${name} font-size is: `, size, document.createElement("br"));
      }
      add("div");
      add("span");
    }
  })
</script>
```